# Get all the records from 1sheet to another sheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I need to get all the records if the filter is "deleted" and I need to automatically populate it in another sheet in the same excel. For example,

**Sheet 1:**

```
Filter  | Id     | Name                  | Username

Added   | 58621  | IDR User2             | AIG_IDR

Deleted | 59088  | Clearwater Analytics  | AIGTessa2

Deleted | 59422  | Janine Mullin         | 32313082

Added   | 59424  | Jonathan Lawless      | 3231367
```

In **sheet 2**, it should automatically add or list all the deleted filter.

```
Filter  | Id     | Name                  | Username

Deleted | 59088  | Clearwater Analytics  | AIGTessa2

Deleted | 59422  | Janine Mullin         | 32313082
```

Is it possible to do that? If yes, can you give me an idea on how to do that? Using conditional formula.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work with minor tweaking:

```
Dim shtNew As Worksheet, shtOrg As Worksheet

Set shtOrg = ActiveSheet
Set shtNew = Sheets.Add

With shtOrg.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Deleted"

    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy shtNew.Cells(1, 1)

    .AutoFilter
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sheet 1 data occupies columns A to D, each line item has a unique ID (in column B), and you want to extract only the "deleted" line items from sheet 1 to sheet 2, then an array formula using `INDEX, SMALL and ROW` should be sufficient to get the ID's of deleted entries, and a simple `INDEX + MATCH` combo for the other column data referenced to the ID's returned.

Assuming we want to start the list in row 2 of sheet 2, copy the following formula in cell B2:

```
=iferror(index(sheet1!b:b,small(if(sheet1!a:a="deleted",row(sheet1!a:a)),row(1:1))),"")
```

Be sure to press `CONTROL + SHIFT + ENTER` when returning the said formula. After doing this, you can now drag down the formula to return all IDs of deleted entries. When it starts returning blank values, it would mean all IDs of deleted entries are already returned.

Next, in columns A, C and D of sheet 2, enter the following:

```
=iferror(index(sheet1!a:a,match(b2,sheet1!b:b,0)),"")
```

No need for the `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER` when applying this. For this, just change a:a to c:c for Name and d:d for username. Again, this assumes that the first ID value is in row 2 (cell B2), from which our `MATCH` are referenced.